# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode' while trying to decode string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, encoding

I am running this code on Python 3. I encoded the data using `.encode('utf_8')` while accepting from the server. But now I want to `decode` it in order make it human readable.

```
 All1 = soup.findAll('tag_name', class_='class_name')
 All2 = "".join([p.text for p in All1])
 str = "1",All2.encode('utf_8')
 print(str.decode('utf_8'))
```

But it is giving the following error:

```
print(str.decode('utf_8'))
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

How can I decode it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` (don't name your variables after built-in functions, by the way) is a `tuple`, not a string.

```
str = "1",All2.encode('utf_8')
```

This is equivalent to the more readable:

```
str = ("1", All2.encode('utf_8'))
```

I don't know what you need the `"1"` for, but you might try this:

```
num, my_string = '1', All2.encode('utf_8')
```

And then decode the string:

```
print(my_string.decode('utf_8'))
```

Comment: If someone could explain what's wrong with this answer that makes it deserve a downvote, I would love to improve it.

Comment: This line `print(my_string.decode('utf_8'))` gave me a direction. Thanks @TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 1):

I run into this error frequently using SageMaker Pipelines. If you are in the same boat and are lost because the logs are not at all pointing you to what portion of code is causing `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'`, I can tell you that for me it *always* occurs because I have a dangling comma that I introduced at the end of some line of code (and my IDE did not complain about).

I've realized I induce this error whenever I am copying and pasting code or am refactoring.

For example

```py
func(
    a=funcA(...),
    b=funcB(...),
)
```

gets refactored into

```py
a=funcA(...),
b=funcB(...),
func(
    a=a,
    b=b,
)
```

where I have just copy pasted lines of code and kept problematic commas! Instead, remember to clean them up as

```py
a=funcA(...)
b=funcB(...)
func(
    a=a,
    b=b,
)
```